# Libgdx change to other screen and dispose current one

Tags: libgdx, rendering, box2d, screen

I am trying to switch to a GameScreen when the LinearVelocity of a Box2D - Object is x = 0. 
If it is so, I am using the setScreen() - Method by calling the main class. This works perfekt, but when the screen should change, it just flickers, which is most likely caused by the render() - method in the screen class. 
So my question is now, how to dipose that render method or how to dispose the whole screen class, so that I only the new screen appears!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **libGDX** `Game` class delegates to a single `Screen` so if your game is flickering between the new `Screen` and the old `Screen` after you call `Game.setScreen` it is likely because the new `Screen` sets the old screen back.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I supposed to be the problem. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The problem was, that the new Screen was actually empty resulting in an emtpy render - method aswell.